# html tag not working in jquery and php

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to make auto suggestion using jquery plugins and php. But in jquery variable php working but html not. my codes are following:

```
<?php 
include 'sql.php';
?>
<script>
$(function() {
var availableTags = [
"<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM new_vendor GROUP BY company";
        $result = $cn->query($sql);
            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo $row["company"]."<br>";

                    }} ?>"
 ];
 $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
 source: availableTags
 });
 });
 </script>

 <div class="ui-widget">
<label for="tags">Tags: </label>
<input id="tags">
</div>
```

br tag not working. please help
it gives result like:
abcdefsdfass
but I need result like : 
abc
def
sdf
ass

Comment: What's the problem you are facing

Comment: I am getting result like that : abc<br/>def<br/>ghi<br/>jkl<br/>

Comment: So update your question  with expected result

Comment: I update my question please check

Comment: when I am using \n its not loading. its shows same result

Comment: I have uploaded an answer check if it works

Answer (score 0):

It's going to echo out `<br>` to the browser, which in HTML terms, will mean render a new line. Right there, you're in javascript, which isn't interpreted by the html parser.

I think this is what you want:

```
var availableTags = [
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM new_vendor GROUP BY company";
        $result = $cn->query($sql);
            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo '"' . $row["company"] . "\",\n";

                    }} ?>
 ];
```

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? I did a simple array, and the syntax appears to be correct.

Comment: no error message. but i don't get any value in input form

Comment: Right click => view source, and see what is between the brackets (`[` and `]`). You may not have any data in the database.